# How to solve form validation problem in slick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I use slick slider in bootstrap modal where i show input fields in each slick , but when i validate it always show empty field even all are filled , i see the problem that when i press next arrow button of slick it first shows empty input then instantaneously fills it with what i enter before , how to solve this

Here is a minimalist reproduction of the issue.

```js
$(() => {
  $(".slick-products").slick({
    dots: true
  });
});

function test() {
  const result = $("form")[0].checkValidity()
    ? 'valid'
    : 'invalid';
  $('#output').html('');
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#output').html(result);
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <form>
      <div class="slick-products">
        <div>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div><input type="text" required /></div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button><br/>
    Test result: <span id="output"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Enter some text into the input box and press the Test button. I'm expecting it to test out as "valid" but instead I see "invalid" even though the only required input has been set.

If I remove the second `<div><input type="text" required /></div>` so that the slider only has one item, it starts testing as "valid".

Comment: help somebody site is in production

Comment: It would help to see your `<script src"whatever"></script>` tags so we know precisely what libraries you are using. Also if you have any javascript you wrote you might want to post that too. The problem needs to be reproduced here before anyone can do much to help.

Comment: @RockySims ok I add scripts

Comment: @RockySims yes added

Comment: Cool, and where is `open_filter_modal` defined?

Comment: @RockySims it is not required in this case and can be removed , important are slick slides

Comment: I've updated your question so it can run here but I'm guessing there is still something missing since I'm not seeing a slider. Click Run Code Snippet (in your question) and tell me if that looks right or not. Not trying to fix anything yet just trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think what is missing is the javascript where you run `.slick()` on the slider element.

Comment: @RockySims ok I give

Comment: @RockySims `$("#slick-optional").slick({
  dots: true});

$(".slick-products").slick({
  dots: true});`

Comment: @RockySims to check validity do this on button click  `if($("#review")[0].checkValidity()){ alert("valid");}else{ $("#review")[0].reportValidity(); } `

Comment: @RockySims sorry i will help u reproduce this wait 2 mins

Comment: @RockySims check it now it is not showing arrow but u can click on dots and fill fields , only name and image is mandatory but check it always shows required even when i fill everything in this, also when i remove form validity only those value is sent which is visible currently

Comment: Okay, so I'm seeing the slider working. I'm assuming we are focused on the second slider. What are the exact steps to reproduce the problem and what is the actual vs expected result?

Comment: @RockySims My problem is that i am doing form validation , i fill the above form but it always says please fill this field , please click on test me at bottom

Comment: @RockySims are you able to replicate the problem ?

Comment: I think so. I fill in the name input with "a", click the dot to go to the other name input, enter "b" in that second name input, choose an image, and then click "Test me" and I see that `$("#review")[0].checkValidity()` is `false` even though it seems like it should be `true`.

Comment: @RockySims yeah

Comment: I've pared it down to the minimal code require to reproduce the problem. Not sure yet what's wrong.

Comment: @RockySims new edit is not working please undo

Comment: I think it is working just pared way down so there is hardly anything there. Are you sure it isn't working?

Comment: I think I've found a solution. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: @Rocky sims Yes it was not working u did not added input in second div and just write two , i correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that slick slider tries to do infinite scrolling by default. To do that it has to clone another copy of the slider item so it's ready to move into place when sliding around the world (forward from last to first or backwards from first to last). That cloned copy of the slider item contains another `<input required ...` element  which is still empty and therefore the form is invalid.

Looks like the easiest fix is to just set infinite scroll to false by adding

`infinite: false`

to the slick config object.

```js
$(() => {
  $(".slick-products").slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false
  });
});

function test() {
  const result = $("form")[0].checkValidity()
    ? 'valid'
    : 'invalid';
  $('#output').html('');
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#output').html(result);
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <form>
      <div class="slick-products">
        <div>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" required />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button><br/>
    Test result: <span id="output"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you enter text in both input boxes (1 per slider item) then click the Test button, it tests out as "valid".